# Using if/else structure in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, if-else

I wrote some simple code to test the if/else structure in GEE:

```
var flag = ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(1,5);
print(flag)
if (flag) {
 print("this is true");
} else {
 print("this is false");
}
```

the output was:

```
false;
this is true
```

Does anyone know how to adjust the above statement to be effective?

Comment: Note that you are using a server-side Earth Engine object in a client-side operation. Earth Engine objects in the client are interpreted as a JSON strings and strings are converted to boolean in JavaScript `if()` if there is no expression to evaluate. Since the JSON string is not `null` it converts to `true`.  [More on Client vs Server](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/client_server), [More on JS `if()` and strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4923631/why-does-ifstring-evaluate-string-as-true-but-if-string-true-does-not).

Comment: The EE code editor print() function hides some of this semantic. Your print(flag) outputs false, but like Justin points out, it's not a boolean. Look here: https://code.earthengine.google.com/f4801a5b13115c04486c1785c273ce43 At the time you do your if(flag), the value of flag is actually not evaluated yet.

Comment: Good point, Daniel, thanks for noting: `The EE code editor print() function hides some of this semantic`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You typically try to not end up in situations where you do conditionals in EE. If you really, really need it, you can do like this:

```
var flag = ee.Algorithms.IsEqual(1, 5)
print(flag)
var s = ee.Algorithms.If(flag, "this is true", "this is false")
print(s)
```

https://code.earthengine.google.com/d7e786473db194bdb01c32aab034e5d3

Comment: See the [If/Else section](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/tutorial_js_03#ifelse-conditions) of the Earth Engine developer docs for more info on why `ee.Algorithms.If()` should be avoided if possible.